# Duplicating div elements and their CSS on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a page that has a div with the id "exam" and a button with the id "copy". The div includes the text "Exam 1" and has a 2px double black border around it. When the button is clicked, the div element is supposed to be duplicated and displayed below each time the button is clicked. I have gotten that part to work, however, it doesn't seem to be copying the div element's CSS, only the text inside the element, so each time I click the button, it's only displaying "Exam 1", but not the border.

Here is my HTML (this also includes the Javascript and CSS):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Exam 1 Tanner Taylor</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #exam {
                border: 2px double black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="exam">
        Exam 1
        </div>
        <input type="button" id="copy" value="Make Copy" onclick="copy()" >
    </body>

    <script type = "text/javascript">
            var TTi = 0;
            var TToriginal = document.getElementById("exam");
            function copy() {
                var TTclone = TToriginal.cloneNode(true);
                TTclone.id = "exam" + ++TTi;
                TToriginal.parentNode.appendChild(TTclone);
            }
    </script>
</html>
```

There's more to it, but I cut out the portions that didn't deal with this particular issue. Any ideas as to why it's not displaying the border around the text when the button is clicked?

Comment: You are changing the id. It will only change the style if the element's id is `exam`, but it won't change elements with the id `exam1` etc. Perhaps use a class.

Comment: I hadn't even noticed that, thanks for pointing that out. I was able to fix the problem just be removing the + ++TTi from the TTclone declaration. If you want to submit this as an answer I'd be glad to accept it so you get credit for it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The css is only targeting the id `exam` and all clones are changing that id. A possible solution would be to use `[id^="exam"]`.

`^=` says if it starts with "exam" then use this style.

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/xupuqavecope/2/edit

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Exam 1 Tanner Taylor</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            [id^="exam"] {
                border: 2px double black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="exam">
        Exam 1
        </div>
        <input type="button" id="copy" value="Make Copy" onclick="copy()" >
    </body>

    <script type = "text/javascript">
            var TTi = 0;
            var TToriginal = document.getElementById("exam");
            function copy() {
                var TTclone = TToriginal.cloneNode(true);
                TTclone.id = "exam" + ++TTi;
                TToriginal.parentNode.appendChild(TTclone);
            }
    </script>
</html>
```