# JavaScript Reptition of HTML Element

Tags: javascript, html, button, repeat

I'm having a problem with some JavaScript with the repetition of an element.

The question that I have is I have to add a button and every time it is clicked another of the same HTML element with the same text is added to the page.

The example that I'm given is..
"If the user clicked the button 5 times there should no be 5 elements with the text "exam 1" each with their own black border."

The border or creating the button isn't a problem from me. It's the function that repeats the element in the same exact form.

I'm not asking someone to write the entire function for me. Just someone that can explain a good direction to go in. I've looked online and in the book that I have and I've not had any luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated

I know the function has to be something like that...

```
    window.onload = init;
    function init() {
        var button = document.getElementById("addButton");
        button.onclick = handleButtonClick; 
        var button1 = document.getElementById("repeatMe");
        button1.onclick = handleButtonClick;
    }

    function handleButtonClick() {
        var LGtextInput = document.getElementById("text");
        var LGlistElem = LGtextInput.value;
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = LGlistElem;
        var LGul = document.getElementById("list");
        LGul.appendChild(li);
    }
```

This repeats the text entered into an unordered list, would I change the name to repeat a different element? (I want the element to be a heading tag)

Comment: How do you think you should approach this problem?

Comment: I know that it has to be a function something like this...

Comment: Deja vu... I just answered a question identical to this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070052/duplicating-div-elements-and-their-css-on-button-click.  Is this a homework assignment or something?

Comment: Sorry I posted it above. It was easier to read

Comment: Dom thank you.. This actually is an assignment but I've never heard of that person. Thank you for linking me to this other page.

Comment: I'm fairly new to javascript. I come here to get help...not be made fun of.